# Custom Error 403 Page PHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I created a .htaccess inside a directory in which I don't want the files to be directly accessed. It works and fires the default 403 page (Access forbidden!) of the Apache server. How can I create a custom 403 page? Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file you can specify what document you want as your default 403 error document.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /dir/file.html
```

Here the directory is relative to the document root.

Answer (score 14):

You can do something like the following:

```
#Rewrite URL's
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^404/?$ errors/404.html [NC]

# Enable Error Documents
# (404,File Not Found) | (403,Forbidden) | (500,Internal Server Error)
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 403 /404
```

What this is doing is turning on the RewriteEngine so we can redirect url's nicely, then we are defining using the RewriteRule that /404/ or /404 should redirect to the custom 404 page. I then state that the ErrorDocument 404 and 403 should redirect to the 404 page. I do this for security so, a user does not know whether or not a file exists or if they just don't have access.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add a custom inline error message via ErrorDocumnet in your .htaccess file as shown below:

```
    ErrorDocument 403 '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><p>Sorry, access to this page is forbidden.</p></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 2):

None is worked for me. I had to edit the file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/localized-error-pages.conf` and add the following

```
ErrorDocument 403 "403, Ok!?"
```