# access denied 403 redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, http-status-code-403

I have an image folder with all the user profile pics in the webroot.
Now I want to protect it with an htaccess file and options-indexes.
It works fine, but I want yii to redirect the user to my special forbidden view instead of showing this ugly 403 access denied apache site.

I tried the following code in my `actionError`() in the Site Controller, but doesn't work.

```
 if (Yii::app()->errorHandler->error['code'] == 403)
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
```

Comment: this may help you  ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703540/custom-error-403-page-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the pictures are requested in a pattern like http://www.mydomain.com/pics/mypic.jpg yii is nowhere invoked so you can't achieve a redirection with the yii framework.

As @SuVeRa proposed on his comment you 'd better use the .htaccess to do the redirection e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /dir/file.html
```