# 403 error page not rendered in my live hosting?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cpanel

i am using laravel 5.3, my render function for displaying errors is:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if($this->isHttpException($e)){
            if (view()->exists('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode()))
            {
                return response()->view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [], $e->getStatusCode());
            }

        }
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

and i have the 403, 404 and 503 errors page in errors folder..

the 404 page works...so if i entered a page is not in my site the 403 blade return ....but when i try to access some folders...and i got the default cpanel forbidden page.....so how can i display the error page for 403 error.
thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703540/custom-error-403-page-php

Comment: stills not show up my 403 custom page....it just shows 404 page !