ErrorDocument 403 not working on Apache server with custom HTML error page (Forbidden 403 error encountered)
I want my error pages to be costumed. I already have created a html file for the 403 status webpage.
I followed also the correct answer in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703540/custom-error-403-page-php
and this is what my .htaccess looks like:
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1.php [NC,L]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /errorPages/error403.html

the path is correct but This is the output I am receiving.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

My server is Linux, so I use Apache as the web server.

Either the web server is not allowed to read the file, or there are other access restrictions in place. Check the file permissions first of all.

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

Does it mean that the URL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703540/custom-error-403-page-php) I referenced is off-topic on Stack Overflow because it's related to system configuration? Please enlighten me.

How are you triggering the 403?

I figured out the solution; I need to add the 'public_html' folder name before my '/errorPages' folder.
so it should be:
ErrorDocument 403 public_html/errorPages/error403.html


Although that doesn't look correct at all. The URL-path argument is root-relative, so should start with a slash. And public_html should not be present in the URL-path, unless you really do have a public_html directory in the public HTML space. (But why would you have a public_html directory in the public HTML space? That itself looks like a config error.)

And, unless you have something else in your config, this alone would not resolve the "Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered..." issue that seems to be the main point addressed in your question. This is possibly dependent on how the 403 is triggered in the first place (hence my comment under your question).
